# JMeter - Replace inline javaScript to BeanShell

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

I need to send elapsed time in header of each request. To do this I use inline javaScript in HTTP Header Manager as following:

[image]

If there is any way to do the same with BeanShell instead of javaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [since JMeter 3.1 you are supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so here is something similar for the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) / 1000).round(1),)}
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Just a small comment - to return seconds as an integer (as in my javascript example) - round(1) should be changed to round(0) or even just round().